# Wordpress icon fonts dont work with www url

Tags: url, no-www, fonts, icon

I have wordpress site with domain `domain.com` and on one site i use font icons. The problem is when I change in settings Address site (URL) on `www.domain.com`. Sites works properly, I seu www in URL but font icons doesnt work (it shows blank square instead).

I want to have either i type `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` in browser url that the site show up with www and icon fonts will works

httaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm using wp svg icons

Without www

[image]

With www in settings

[image]

The problem is that this is not affecting only this wp svg icons plugin but also others

Comment: Sorry but there is not enough information to be able to answer your question without speculating. We have no information of the fonts you are using nor how they are being loaded when a visitor visits the sites, if you have updated the WordPress Address and the Site Address found in settings > general etc. Also if you have ever edited .htaccess it would be ideal to add that too. Sharing the site address sometimes helps too, in short... we need more information.

Comment: I found this in web console:  downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: (here is url without www)

Comment: Ok, i found a solution i set only website address with www and i had to set wordpress address with www also

Comment: Which I suggested `if you have updated the WordPress Address and the Site Address found in settings > general etc`